# Python: Convert a String into a tuple or list with a twist

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a set of data that looks like so:

```
OutletCntrTemp|25degreesC|ok
InletTemp|17degreesC|ok
PCHTemp|46degreesC|ok
P0ThermMargin|-57degreesC|ok
P1ThermMargin|-59degreesC|ok
P0DIMMTemp|27degreesC|ok
P1DIMMTemp|27degreesC|ok
HSC0InputPower|60Watts|ok
HSC0InputVolt|12.46Volts|ok
CPU0Tjmax|90degreesC|ok
......
```

Now I want to loop through this data and create a list or a tuple in a function and return each row but name that tuple using the first part of the string:

```
CPUTjmax = ('90degreesC','ok')
```

now i did some spliting up of the string via | but hit a wall when i tried to use `string[0] = (string[1],string[2])` to define the tuple.

Could anyone give me a pointer here please.

Ric

Comment: You can't dynamically create variables (well, you can, but you shouldn't). Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you can do is, create a `dict`, and add them as key:value pair in it:

```
>>> d = dict()
>>> 
>>> s = 'CPU0Tjmax|90degreesC|ok'
>>> li = s.split("|")
>>> 
>>> d[li[0]] = (li[1], li[2])
>>> d
{'CPU0Tjmax': ('90degreesC', 'ok')}
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly don't want to create variables, use a `dict` instead:

```
data = [
    'CPU0Tjmax|90degreesC|ok',
    'InletTemp|17degreesC|ok'
]
d = {el[0]: tuple(el[1:]) for el in (item.split('|') for item in data)}
# {'InletTemp': ('17degreesC', 'ok'), 'CPU0Tjmax': ('90degreesC', 'ok')}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use should definitely use a dictionary variable.

For completeness here a non-standard solution for creating new local variables:

```
for line in open("data.dat"):
   e=line.split("|")
   locals()[e[0]] = ( e[1], e[2] )
```

Internally, the local variables are also a dictionary which you can access with `locals()`.
However, as [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) says:

> The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for your comment, I extended the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are good. Here is one more way, similar to the answer using `locals()`. You just create an empty object, and fill its __dict__:

```
class X(object):
    pass

Var = X()

for ...:
    Var.__dict__[string[0]] = (string[1], string[2])

#now you can refer to your vars as Var.whatever
if Var.InletTemp[1] != 'ok':
    ...
```